# Error with Boost.Python when returning a reference to a custom object

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

EDIT: I noticed my question was not clear enough; I hadn't specified n0 was an attribute of Edge.

I have two classes Nodes and Edges. Edge is defined (I omitted lots of methods and attributes that are of no interest here):

```
class Edge()
{
  Node& n0;
public:
  const Node& N0() const;
};
```

The accessor is coded as follows:

```
Node const& Edge::N0() const
{
  return n0;
};
```

where n0 is a private reference to a Node() instance. The problem is that, while trying to expose this function with the following code:

```
class_<Edge>("Edge", init<Node&,Node&>())
    .add_property("n0",&Edge::N0,return_internal_reference<>());
```

(the class Node is exposed right before) 
I get the error:

> error: cannot create pointer to reference member ‘Edge::n0’

I could make the accessor return a copy of n0, and it would work fine (tested). However, if n0 were to be really heavy I would prefer for performance issues to return a const reference rather than a copy.

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with what I am doing? I am pretty new to C++ and Boost.Python and admittedly don't understand much about the call policies yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 years later, you can still do it via `add_property` if you use `boost::python::make_function`:

```
class_<Edge>("Edge", init<Node&,Node&>())
    .add_property(
        "n0", 
        make_function(&Edge::N0, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()));
```

Answer (score 3):

So, I still don't understand why my orginal program or @ForEveR 's solutions won't work, but I did find a workaround that gives me what I wanted.

First, in the file where the edge class is defined, I defined the following function:

```
Node const& Edge_get_nodes(Edge& self)
{
   return self.N0(); 
};
```

And I wrote for the wrapper:

```
class_<Edge>("Edge", init<Node&,Node&>())
   .add_property("length",&Edge::GetLength)
   .def("GetNode",&Edge_get_nodes,return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
```

Now, when I import the module in python, I can get n0 doing the following:

```
e1.GetNode()
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help!

(if someone can explain to me why it works like this and not the other way, I'd be happy to know!)

Answer (score -1):

```
// property creation
    template <class Get>
    void add_property(char const* name, Get const& fget, char const* doc=0);
    template <class Get, class Set>
    void add_property(
        char const* name, Get const& fget, Set const& fset, char const* doc=0);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec

so

```
class_<Edge>("Edge", init<Node&,Node&>())
    .add_property("n0",&Edge::N0, "get private edge");
```

should works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The compiler stopped to insult me over several lines. However, I now have a error saying "error: cannot create pointer to reference member ‘Edge::n0’". 
But how is  that a problem since I return a reference to a const (hence cannot modify the value)? In that particular example I could simply return a copy of n0, but what if I wanted to return a really heavy object?

Comment: And how about use def("n0", &Edge::N0, return_internal_reference<>)?, or add_propery("n0", make_getter(&Edge::N0, return_internal_reference<>)), "edge getter") or simply use add_property("n0", make_getter(&Edge::N0), "edge getter") ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had tried previously the first solution you propose, it doesn't work for the same reason as above (complains that n0 is private and then "cannot create pointer to reference member ‘Edge::n0’"). Your other propositions lead to the exact same error.

Comment: Ok, i think it`s unreal. There are no variants to return reference/pointer to member. Mb you can use some wrapper or something else, but there is no variants how use do this without some magic.

Comment: Yes, I tried to work around this and it finally worked! I'm not sure I need to return by reference, but I think that if I need to access a big object (like a big adjacency list with a million nodes) that is a class attribute, it is way faster to return a reference than the value, no?
Actually, how does it work when python works with the reference? Does it copy the object anyway? If you have any link to something that could explain that to me, I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: So if you have list with 1000000 elements it`s better to use for this list of pointers (native or smarts). In Python all non-atomic types (i.e. simple types as int, long ect) are reference-types. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29